# How can you write assign a default value from an array when the element does not exist?

Tags: c#

This situation has always nagged me.  Just as an example, suppose a console application expects filepath in as a command line argument.

```
string first = args[0];
```

but if there are no arguments, then an error will occur.  I suppose I could do something like the following:

```
string first = (args[0]!=null) ? args[0] : "c:\";
```

What I'm looking for is something a bit more elegant like:

```
string first = (MyTryParse(args[0],"c:\");
```

Which I could write as an extension, however that won't work because args[0] will throw an exception before the method can be called.

Comment: Test for `args.length` first. If it's zero then nothing was passed.

Answer (score 3):

Also check, if `args[0]` is null:

```
public string MyTryParse(string[] args, int index, string defaultVal)
{
    return index < args.Length ? (args[index] ?? defaultVal) : defaultVal
}
...
string first = MyTryParse(args, 0, "c:\");
```

Comment: @w.b as `args` is just a simple array, there is no guarantee `args[0]` is not null, so my method is for common cases

Comment: The OP said it's a console application, args can be empty, but args[0] can't be null

Answer (score 1):

Pass `args` instead of `args[0]`

Try like this

```
public string MyTryParse(string[] args, string defaultVal) {
    return args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : defaultVal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same approach but using `extension` method,

```
public static class Extensioin
{
    public static string MyTryParse(this string[] args, string defaultVal)
    {
        return args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : defaultVal;
    }
}
```

And using above method something like this,

```
string first = args.MyTryParse(@"c:\");
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ already has [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) method for that purpose:

```
string first = args.DefaultIfEmpty("c:\\").First();
```